# Returning multiple valuables and then calling those valuables separately

Tags: python

I'm having issue with allowing a function to call on variables set by another function. I believe I know how to do this with single variables, but my code requires it be done with multiple variables, a challenge I've struggled with for hours. I've read much about ways others seem to have done this but I can't find success in implementing them.

```
#gathers the user's requests
def ask():
    userw = int(input('How wide? '))
    userh = int(input('How tall? '))
    userc = input('What string to use? ')
    userc_len = int(len(userc))
    return (userw, userh, userc, userc_len)

#draws the rows of the box. First the top with the topbot function, then the body with body(), then the bottom with topbot again
def draw(w, h, c, c_len):
    def topbot(w_, c_):
        for x in range(w_):
            print (c_, end ='')
            print ('\n')
    def body(w_, h_, c_, c_len_):
        for x in range(h_-2):
            print (c_, end = '')
            for x in range(w_-2):
                print(' ' * c_len_, end = '')
            print (c_)

    topbot(w, c)
    body(w, h, c, c_len)
    topbot(w, c)

#begins draw    
draw(userw, userh, userc, userc_len)
```

The problem begins when the `draw` function tries to begin with the arguments of `userw, userh, userc, userc_len`, but can't find them:

```
NameError: name 'userw' is not defined
```

is returned when I try to run it.

1. Is it correct to define `topbot` and `body` within the `draw` function and manage the arguments how I did?
2. How do I return the four variables from `ask` in a manner such that `draw` can then use them as arguments?

Comment: I don't understand why you thought `draw(ask(userw), ask(userh), ask(userc), ask(userc_len))` would work; `ask` doesn't take any arguments, why would you want to call it four times, and how could e.g. `userw` possibly be defined at that point? Instead you want to call it *once* and get all four returned values, e.g. `userw, userh, userc, userc_len = ask()`, or just pass them straight to `draw`: `draw(*ask())` (see http://stackoverflow.com/q/36901/3001761).

Comment: I didn't, I just used that to illustrate what I want to do.

Comment: So that's not even your actual code? Please give a [mcve].

Comment: I did it that way because I don't know what code to use, but I've edited it. Hopefully that makes it more clear what I want to do and what I'm asking about.

Comment: is there really any need to be passing around `c_len`? Since the string doesn't change, it might be more clear to just use `len(c)`

Comment: you're right, I made a variable for len(c) to keep myself organized but in hindsight it does just make things more compilctaed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ask() is a function which will return 4 values. So,

```
returnValues = ask()
draw = draw(*returnValues) 
or simply, draw = draw(*ask())
```

Also, end = ' ' is not correct. Instead of that you can just use print(c_,'').
Include Validations wherever necessary. Like what if I type "hi" for "How wide?". In this case the program should tell me that this is wrong.

Comment: @jep Just for the sake of clarity, `returnValues` will be a tuple, something like (4,5,'o',1), so you could have used `draw = draw(returnValues[0], returnValues[1], returnValues[2], returnValues[3])` however, using the `*returnValues` is certainly nicer and obviously more extensible. It is known as the "splat operator" for variable unpacking.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get `draw()` to accept the inputs from your `ask()` function (in Python IDLE) just by changing the last line of your code to this:

```
draw(*ask())
```

The `*` will unpack the variables from the `ask()` call and pass that along to `draw()`.  The output looks kind of funny, and I'm not sure whether that's what you're looking for or not, but at least it got the variables in there correctly.